# Operations immediately after dialog box appears

Tags: mfc, dialog

I am working with MFC project. I have a situation where I want to do an extensive calculation as soon as the dialog box shows up.
I tried putting this calculations in OnInitDialog() and also tried putting it in the contructor. For obvious reasons, with this approach, it takes time for the dialog box to appear which is not intended.

Is there a way where I can do my calculations immediately after the dialog box shows up? If so which is the function that I need to fit my code into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BOOL CMFC_dialogDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
 AfxBeginThread(ThreadFunc,NULL/*Pass the parameter to the function*/);
}

UINT ThreadFunc(LPVOID param)
{
 /*Do complex task*/

 for(int i=0;i<1000 ;i++)
 {
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, creating another thread from the constructor or `OnInitDialog` override is the approach for this problem. But for giving notification back to dialog box that *Complex initialization is complete*, you need to use `SendMessage` or `PostMessage` to let dialog-window know about this completion and update the UI appropriately. You would also need to have custom message-code (WM_USER+*N*, or WM_APP+*N*), along with an entry in message-map: `ON_MESSAGE`.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation you'll need to do the caculations in a subthread.Usually I do this job using [AfxBeginThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).